# joomla user selection modal (backend) not working, any idea?

Tags: joomla, modal-dialog

I am working on joomla 2.5.8 version.
Everything is working fine, but i have a problem while loading user modal.

1. [image]

2.After clicking set user button  this page will appear . 
[image]

But, modal could not load :( and after clicking user, username couldn't fill on created by section.

i think following image make us clear. but it's not user modal it is menu modal. 
what is the problem ?

[image]

Comment: Joomla 2.5.8 or 2.5.28?

Comment: Well please udate your site to 2.5.28 which is the latest version. You're about 20 minor versions behind so you don't have the latest security updates and bug fixes.